# using localization service GetAllLanguages from a component composer, incorrect DI?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

I have an interface as below, which I use to add a specific language if it does not exist:

```
public interface IGetLanguagesService
    {
        void GetLanguages(ILocalizationService localization);
    }


    public class LanguageService : IGetLanguagesService
    {
        ILocalizationService _localizationService;
        public void GetLanguages(ILocalizationService localization)
        {
            _localizationService = localization;
            var currentLanguages = _localizationService.GetAllLanguages();
            bool exists = false;
            foreach (var currentLan in currentLanguages)
            {
                if (currentLan.IsoCode == "es-ES")
                {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if (!exists)
            {
                AddLanguage(_localizationService);
            }
        }

        public void AddLanguage(ILocalizationService localization)
        {
            var languageSE = new Language("es-ES") { CultureName = "es-ES", IsMandatory = true };
            localization.Save(languageSE);
        }
    }
```

I want to use this at start-up so have created a component composer, which on Initialize() I want to call CallGetLanguages() but Im not entirely sure what should be in Initialize(), I think my DI may be wrong?

```
   public class LanguagesComposer : ComponentComposer<LanguagesComponent>
        {
            public void Compose(Composition composition)
            {
                composition.Register<IGetLanguagesService>(Lifetime.Singleton);
                composition.Register<ILocalizationService>(Lifetime.Singleton);

                composition.Components().Append<LanguagesComponent>();
            }
        }

        public class LanguagesComponent : IComponent
        {
            public void Initialize()
            {
               ???????
            }

            public void Terminate()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            IGetLanguagesService _getLanguagesService;
            ILocalizationService _localization;
            public void CallGetLanguages(IGetLanguagesService getLanguages, ILocalizationService localization)
            {
                _getLanguagesService = getLanguages;
                _localization = localization;
                _getLanguagesService.GetLanguages(localization);
            }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed `ILocalizationService localization` instance to `LanguageService` twice, pass it to constructor instead and use a constructor injection. The same issue with `LanguagesComponent`, pass all its dependencies to constructor instead of methods